# Getting a LSB of a BMP binary image

Tags: c#, image-processing

i was already able to convert a `BMP` image into  binary `memory stream`  but im confused with detecting LSB in pixel values..

I have the `byte[] stream` as `'10101011101010101010010'` ... .. ..

First is there a way that i can filter this binary stream to pixel values and detect LSB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read / write the Least Significant Byte to use the bitmap to hide information you will need to load the bmp data into an image, then access the pixel-data using [`GetPixel()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx). The BMP File itself might use RLL or some other compression so you cannot access the pixel data directly.

For detecting LSB in an image, it largely depends on the algorithm used, some are harder to detect as others. Do you have the description of the LSB-variant that might be in that image?